# angularjs Resolve undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get resource data from server and pass it to modal.

But I am getting the error **undefined.**

I think modal is executing without waiting for data , please help me to resolve this issue.

I have use the following code  :

**controller1**

```
   $aside.open({
            templateUrl: 'js/view/aside.html',
            placement: position,
            size: 'md',
            backdrop: true,
            controller: 'asidereport',
            resolve: {
                cookies: getPreData
            }
        }).result.then(postClose, postClose);
    }

 GetParamsService.get({
                token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1NzhlMDMzMmRjM2EwZDhjMTFiZmI5ZDgiLCJkYXRlIjoxNDY5NTI0MjcwODkxfQ.iAd6z8afajxwWPM6UDF6mHzjlrn4eqR42XW1HhZjB7Q",
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                }
                var res = data.data;
                console.log(data);
                return res;
 });
```

**Factory**

```
 Myapp.factory('GetParamsService', function($resource) {

   return $resource('http://localhost:8000/v1/admin/filter_report', {}, {
   get: {
       method: 'GET'
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Can you show the code  GetParamsService.get function?

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do this is to wait the data before opening the modal:

```
GetParamsService.get({token: 'yourToken',}, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
   }

   var res = data.data;

   $aside.open({
       templateUrl: 'js/view/aside.html',
       placement: position,
       size: 'md',
       backdrop: true,
       controller: 'asidereport',
       resolve: {
          cookies: res
       }
   }).result.then(postClose, postClose);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the GetParamsService.get is promise. You should put function open modal into callback function GetParamsService.

```
GetParamsService.get({
token:"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1NzhlMDMzMmRjM2EwZDhjMTFiZmI5ZDgiLCJkYXRlIjoxNDY5NTI0MjcwODkxfQ.iAd6z8afajxwWPM6UDF6mHzjlrn4eqR42XW1HhZjB7Q"}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }
            var res = data.data;
            console.log(data);
      $aside.open({
        templateUrl: 'js/view/aside.html',
        placement: position,
        size: 'md',
        backdrop: true,
        controller: 'asidereport',
        resolve: {
            cookies: function() {return res;}
        }
    }).result.then(postClose, postClose);
}
});
```